# git command to update specific module

Tags: git

I got two projects and two distinct git (let call them A & B).

When I work on A, I need sometimes to update the code in B. Here's the workflow:

- code/`add/commit/push` on B
- delete B module in A node_modules
- delete package-lock.json in A
- `npm update` on A
- `npm install` on A

This is pretty ugly and to make matters worses, very slow.

I do this because it's the only way I found to systematically get the updates I want.

Are you aware of the command that I miss ?
Do you know a cleaner workflow I could use ?

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by "git update" and "git install"? I haven't come across those before, myself. Do you mean npm update and install?

Comment: Oh my .. It's late here. Sleepy typo, I edit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just added in my scripts:

```
"npm uninstall MODULENAME && npm install \"git+ssh://git@github.com:GITDEPOT/MODULENAME#master\""
```

It works like a charm.

EDIT: For separation of concerns sake, if you need to work with differents repo on your local enivronnement, you'de better have to use your local src in your package.json.

No need to update things each time something move somewhere, no headaches, no injuries; just fun. Exemple:

```
"dependencies": {
...
"separateModule": "file:../../anotherDir"
}
```

Then you can just import your module as you'd do with a common "node_modules":

```
import MyOwnPleasure from "Delighted"
```